# "Es" in "Es ist gutes Wetter"

Tags: grammar-identification

Ich suche nach der Wortart oder dem korrekten Begriff für das "Es" in "Es ist gutes Wetter". Es ist nämlich kein Personalpronomen. Ich hatte das mal in einem Seminar über Grammatik, habe aber vergessen, wie man das nennt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es ist zwar ein Pronomen, aber, wie du richtig erkannt kein Personalpronomen. Dieses *es* ist nämlich ein [Expletivum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum). Wikipedia kann dir mehr darüber erzählen.

Hier findest du eine Ergänzung zu diesem Thema, am Beispiel des Satzes *[Es lag ein Bischof tot in einer Mur ...](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2-Stellung#Besetzung_des_Vorfelds)*

Comment: Ja genau das war der Begriff den ich gesucht habe!