# "Es waren … darunter"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *["Es" in "Es ist gutes Wetter"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40596/es-in-es-ist-gutes-wetter)*
>   However, that answer is in German, and clearly, my grasp of German is not sufficient to understand a nuianced answer.

I came across this sentence in a *Ersteleser* version of *Die Schatzinsel*:

> Es waren seltsame, manchmal auch unheimliche Kerle darunter.

I can't reconcile "Es" with "waren". Or, if "waren" refers to "die Kerle", what role is "Es" playing?

The general meaning seems to be "It was weird, sometimes strange guys would come by." (refering to the "Gasthaus").

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Es" in "Es ist gutes Wetter"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40596/es-in-es-ist-gutes-wetter)

Comment: **Dupe close voters:** please note, that the [linked question is in German](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language).

Comment: @PiedPiper: please do not vote to close as dupe if the other question was in another language (comment or edit instead).

Comment: Abgesehen davon, daß das Platzhalter-*es* kein Wetter-*es* ist.

Comment: @PiedPiper The first link discusses the same topic. The other two are different.

Comment: @DavidVogt I agree two of those are different. But that still leaves us with at least one duplicate

Comment: ***Es** waren .... darunter* =~ ***There** were ... among them*.

Comment: Es ist die Frage, ob wir ein Tag "Es" gründen sollten, um in der Tagdescription auf die 1-2 Toptopics zu verlinken, die die Frage behandeln, da sich nach "es" schlecht suchen lässt, wobei die zweite Frage ist, ob es über ein Es-Topic leichter gefunden würde. Es gibt einige weitere Fragen, die oft an konkreten Beispielen aufgehängt werden und sich daher schlecht suchen/finden lassen, weil der nächste mit der im Prinzip gleichen Frage ein ganz anderes Beispiel hat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Es** waren seltsame, manchmal auch unheimliche Kerle darunter.

***There*** were strange, sometimes also scary guys among them.

German uses **es** in more situations than English uses *it*. Here, *dort* is not the correct translation for *there*, it must be **es**. That is because we aren't talking about a real place.

Comment: Ich würde sogar sagen, dass überhaupt nicht von einem Platz, real oder irreal, die Rede ist. Gut - ausgeschlossen ist nicht, dass diese Kerle unter einer Brücke waren. Ich tippe aber auf eine Menschengruppe oder -menge.

Comment: @PiedPiper: Janka wrote about real places.

Comment: Until I read your translation, I thought that "seltsame" was describing the situation.  When one realizes it is describing the people, this is much easier to parse. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This type of *es* is known as *Platzhalter-es*. It is a special type of expletive. An expletive is a word that does not contribute to the meaning of a sentence. This *es* is special in that it only appears in front of the verb. Therefore, your sentence could be rewritten as:

> Seltsame, manchmal auch unheimliche Kerle waren darunter.

Clearly, *es* is not the subject here. The subject is *seltsame, manchmal auch unheimliche Kerle*, hence *waren* is plural.

Comment: Is the "es" used here to give "da" something to point to?

Comment: Is ther an implied "gegangen" in this sentence?

Comment: There is no movement. *darunter* = *unter ihnen*, i.e. *unter den Kerlen*. Basically: Some, but not all of the fellows were strange and sometimes also sinister.

Answer (score 3):

It is the same thing as when you say "it is late" in english. What does the  "it" refer to in this case?

So translated it means:

**There were strange, sometimes also frightening guys among them.**